# SwiftUI: How to Pass CoreData Object to Sheet View

Tags: macos, swiftui, core-data

There is a table within a DetailView (NavigationSplitView). The table row provides a context menu in order to enable editing. The views content is from CoreData. When context menu "Edit Item" is chosen a new SheetView should open presenting the content (editable) selected from the table before. But I loose the core data object somehow getting a nil error for `toBeEditedItem` but printing shows the item as available:

**1. table within the DetailsView with the context menu:**

```
struct SecretDetailsView: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
  ...
  // a @State variable to pass the selected table item to the sheet
  @State private var toBeEditedItem: SecretItem!
  @State private var showingDetailSheet = false
      
      var table: some View {
      ...
      } rows: {
        ForEach(secretItems) { secretItem in
            TableRow(secretItem)
                ...
                .contextMenu {
                    Button("Edit Item") {
                        // here table item passed outside table to @State var
                        toBeEditedItem = secretItem
                        // prints the passed item: IS EXISTING!
                        print("item is: \(String(describing: toBeEditedItem))")
                        
                        showingDetailSheet.toggle()  // <-- toggle sheet view
                    }
      }
      // here is the sheet view call
      .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetailSheet,
        onDismiss: didDismiss) {
        SecretDetailSheetView(secretItem: toBeEditedItem)  // <-- NIL ERROR!
    }
}
```

**2. sheet View to show and edit existing content (but never shown due to nil error:**

```
struct SecretDetailSheetView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@ObservedObject var secretItem: SecretItem  // <-- the observed item object
...
}
```

So, somehow the CoreData object is lost between Button action an the sheet view and I don't see why. Any hints, Thanks!

Comment: `@State` is for value types. `NSManagedObject` is reference type and even conforms to `ObservableObject`.  So use `@ObservedObject`. And you could use the `sheet` API which is triggered by an item.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! But with `@ObservedObject var toBeEditedItem: SecretItem` I got this error message `Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable` when passing the item in my Button method `toBeEditedItem = secretItem`. So how do I get the object passed out of the table to the sheet view?

Comment: Use sheet(item:). This will solve your issue you will get the non-optional as an argument

Comment: In your SecretDetailsView struct, you are passing a value to an `@State` variable, not to an `@EnvironmentObject` or an `@StateObject`.  That's why your sheet cannot get the value from secretItem.

Comment: @loremipsum: ok, but where should I use `sheet(item:)? In the context button call? I'm lost...

Comment: @ElTomato: When I use `@EnvironmentObject`  or ?@StateObject` I get an error at `toBeEditedItem = secretItem`: `Cannot assign to property: 'toBeEditedItem' is a get-only property`.

Comment: Yes, get rid of `showingDetailSheet` change `SecretItem!` to `SecretItem?` then the sheet will change to something like `sheet(item: $toBeEditedItem) { toBeEditedItem in` the new `toBeEditedItem` is not `nil`https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)

Comment: @loremipsum, thanks for the link. I managed to adapt the code but the nil-error stays: `.sheet(item: $toBeEditedItem,     onDismiss: didDismiss) {detail in SecretDetailSheetView(secretItem: toBeEditedItem!)
        }`

Comment: @vadian: I cannot use `@ObservedObject` in that case. I just need to pass `secretItem` to an accessible object within the same view. `@ObservedObject is used to pass something to subview`

Comment: Use detail instead. Detail is not nil

Comment: @loremipsum, WHAT THE... That's it! Awesome. But that is nothing somebody can come up with straight. So, why is `detail` not nil but `toBeEditedItem` is becoming nil? I would be happy to rate this as your answer anyway.

Comment: Just call it magic, lol no that is what Apple intends to do with that sheet. nil == not showing, not nil == showing. They pass though the not nil value